# Can't use import framework, have red color

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I installed `pod 'RSKImageCropper'`, but i see in `Pods.xcodeproj` what new framework have red color and i can't

```
import RSKImageCropper
```

xCode wrote `no such module`

in my **swift file**

What could be the problem? and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: remove that line, build your project first, then try again

Comment: @Tj3n if you means remove `pod 'RSKImageCropper'`, it's not help for me

Comment: remove the import line, not the pod line...

Comment: Magic, this helped, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you install pod to swift, it just install files, you need to build your project once for the pod to build the swift module, after that you only can do `import SomeModule` to your project

Answer (score 0):

As @Tj3n said above.

Always clean (cmd + shift + k) and build (cmd + b) after you've installed new pods. Then you can easily `import SomeModule` without having any problem.